Is the English phrase "to make one's day" from Sudden Impact?
In Sudden Impact (1983), the protagonist famously says, "Go ahead, make my day."
I was looking at an ngram for that phrase and found that its usage skyrocketed to modern levels of popularity right around 1983, when the film came out. I knew the line was famous, but I didn't realize that it potentially originated the phrase itself and that the phrase basically didn't exist before then.
Is this really the case?

According to Wikipedia, yes. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_ahead,_make_my_day

It actually says that a different movie used the phrase a year earlier in the exact same context, although indeed apparently it was this movie that brought it to wider notice.

The phrases "Go ahead" and "Make my day" were in common use before Sudden Impact was released, but they were separate.  The film's contribution to popular culture was combining them into one phrase.

Can you back that up with evidence? The ngram seems to disagree.

Your ngram is only for "make my day", again a relatively common phrase that blew up when it was in Sudden Impact. The whole phrase returns no results.

Yes, exactly, that's what I'm saying. I'm well aware the "whole" phrase is from Sudden Impact, that's a given. I'm asking whether "make my day" was in fact a common phrase before Sudden Impact. Because the ngram seems to say no, regardless of you saying yes.

OK, it was a "known" phrase... but again, Sudden Impact blew up "Go Ahead, Make my Day" which is not what you are referring to. The ngram is not relevant to Sudden Impact.

I'm sorry, I don't feel that what you're saying makes any sense and I don't feel I'm apparently able to explain what I'm saying to you. I'm going to just let it go.

"the line was famous [but] its usage skyrocketed [...]" (because of the movie), so one could say that "the phrase basically didn't exist before then" as an everyday word: I guess that's your point, and the possible starting point of the misunderstanding. So, basically, did the movie turn this existing but tasteless sentence into a punchline, correct? :)

ngram viewer suggests that "made/make my day" was already growing as a phrase prior to December 1983: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=made+my+day%2Cmake+my+day&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3 - your own ngram link shows the phrase spiking prior to the movie release.  It could be the phrase was incorporated in the script because it was a new 'modern' phrase.

You say ngram viewer suggests it was not popular before the movie - I see the opposite in the same data.  It was already growing in popularity before the movie came at the end of 1983.  Google's ngram data is from published material, so I can't interpret this as the phrase comes from the movie.

“make someone's day” appears in stories by Larry Niven involving the tasp (a device that can remotely cause bliss in the target), at least in The Ringworld Engineers (1979) if not earlier.

Google Books has numerous examples before Sudden Impact.
Sacred Poetry (1808, though this particular hymn seems to be from 1760):

Yet, though my soul in darkness mourns,
Thy promise is my stay;
Here would I rest till light returns:
Thy presence makes my day.

The Works of James Meikle (1819)

... my kind Lord may make my day bright with his heavenly beams...

Life and Letters of Robert Clement Sconce (1861):

These good Russian girls, too, help make my day cheerful.

Motor Boating magazine (July 1972):

I'm looking forward to more articles by him; they make my day.

Airman magazine (1978)

Articles like these really make my day.

Field and Stream magazine (Feb, 1979):

One fish, well fished for, can more than make my day.

Ducktails & Bobbysox (1980):

... how'd you like to go to the dance with me? That would really make my day complete.


Several of these examples seems like a distinct usage - "make my day" doesn't have the same idiomatic meaning or usage as "make my day ". I can "make my boss happy", but that says absolutely nothing about the frequency or usage of the isolated phrase "make my boss", which is nonsense on its own. "Make my day" and "make my day cheerful" are not really the same phrase.

Only numbers 3, 4 and 5 are the usage that OP is focusing on. 1, 2 and 6 include an adjective which makes for a different meaning.

True, but it's enough to answer the question from the fact that even if you discard those we have 3 citations remaining from before Sudden Impact. We can conclude that the phrase did exist and did not come from this film.

Your Google ngram view suggests it was not from the movie.  Sudden Impact was released in December 1983.  At this time the ngram view suggests the phrase was already gaining in popularity

Even without smoothing, the phrase was already in use in 1983, but grows a lot in 1984, possibly due to the movie.
ngram data has limitations, but I believe it is safe to say that the phrase pre-dates the movie, especially as it comes from published sources.  It would be speculation to say the phrase was included in the movie because it was a new popular phrase, but that wouldn't be far fetched.
I would love to find a source for the phrase, because it clearly originated around this time, but I could not.

This may get downvoted because I can't link citations for it, but as an old person who saw Sudden Impact in the theatre, I think this is a case where the phrase existed well before the film - but the specific flavor of the Dirty Harry usage was new, and that new usage has now become the common usage.
"Make my day", before the film, simply meant "Something pleasant has happened and now my day has been made more enjoyable as a result."  Winning a scratch ticket might "make your day", or seeing a pretty sunset might "make your day".
The Sudden Impact usage added a subtle distinction that approaches but does not quite become irony.  Harry uses it to warn a thief that if he continues to resist, Harry will shoot him.  The implication of the statement is that Harry is the type of guy whose "day will be made" if he gets to shoot someone, because to him getting to kill a thief is a stroke of good fortune that brightens his whole day.  This clip became famous pretty much as soon as the film was released, and was even picked up and re-used by the President.
Because of this, the standard usage shifted slightly, and now "Make my day" has the implication "If you start a fight with me, I will enjoy getting to respond to that, and you will lose and I will enjoy that, too" which was not really present in the original usage.
